# Rescue data from mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb

recently I've got some problems with my old hard drive and windows so I switched over to a new one. I can still access any files on the old hard drive and I still have an installation of mongodb on there with some pretty important data (should have done a backup sometime).

What would be the smartest way to get this data and transfer it to my new instance? Just copying the data files over? This "old" instance is btw not running and its not possible for me to start it again.

Comment: You can simply copy the data of dbPath, but MongoDB must be stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the "old" instance running again by running mongo on the system and pointing the DBPath to the folder on the old hard drive.

It looks like copying the files over is a valid option though.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-cp-or-rsync